# Theming forms in Profile 2

Tags: 7, forms

I was recently introduced into the Profile2 module for adding fields to the registration process and I think it just solves my problem. Can anyone show me how to theme the fields? All I need are the .tpl files but I don't think there are any since it's form so it uses the Form API. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the form will be rendered using the form rendering system, which doesn't include template files, instead functions like [theme_textfield](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7) is used instead. You can choose to let the entire form or certain form elements be rendering by your custom theme function using the `#theme` key.

For certain type of fields, this can be dangerous as they require certain markup.

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes, I too once thought that the Form API was the only way to style my forms. Personally, I think it's a pain in the neck to muck around with form_alter hooks trying to change elements and add the HTML markup you need to style your form; I'd much rather just use one .tpl.php file for the whole thing. And low and behold, you can!

In the following method I define variables from the form that can be outputted in a template file to fit whatever HTML structure you'd like. This assumes knowledge of the form structure. In this case, I'm guessing your form structure is defined in multiple places, depending on what fields compose your users. I'd suggest using a hook_form_alter in your template.php to print out the form array so you can get the form ID and all the info on the elements.

For this method, I put all of my code in template.php, but you can just as easily make a custom module to do this.

1. Add a hook_theme() implementation

   ```
   function YOURTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
         return array(
           'YOUR_FORM_ID' => array(
             'render_element' => 'form',
             'template' => 'user-profile-form',
             'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME') . '/templates', 
             //add '/templates' only if you store template files in an additional folder
           ),
         );
       }
   ```

   This tells the Drupal theming system that there's a template file waiting for it in YOURTHEME/templates.
2. Next we'll define some variables to pass into that template in a hook_preprocess_HOOK function. We can find the structured array of the form in $variables['form'] and assign the form elements to the variables we'd like to throw around our tpl.php file.

   ```
   function YOURTHEME_preprocess_YOUR_FORM_ID(&$variables) {
       $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render($variables['form']['some_form_element']);
       $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render($variables['form']['some_form_element_2']);
     }
   ```

   This example will put both of the selected form elements into a variable called "rendered." Not knowing the structure of the form given from Profile2, I don't know what these elements will be called; again, check the form structure!
3. Now that we have defined a variable, we can output it in a template file. Create a template file named YOUR-FORM-ID.tpl.php in 'YOURTHEME/templates'. This is a demo example:

   ```
   <div id="new-form">
     <?php echo $rendered; ?>
   </div>
   ```

When you visit the page that the Profile2 form is on, you should now see only some_form_element and some_form_element_2. Create different variables in the preprocess function to separate out form elements and place them wherever you wish in the YOUR-FORM-ID.tpl.php file, adding whatever markup you like. If you need to change specific things about each field, you can play with each element individually before it's rendered in the preprocess function by changing any of the Form API tags.

This seems like a lot of info; let me know if you have any questions!